# UWP Grid inside Datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, pivot, computer-science

I have a `Pivot` where I set the header in my `Pivot.HeaderTemplate` it is basically just showing `Names` of Books. In my `Pivot.ItemTemplate` I want to show a `Grid` which is build in my .xaml.cs but since the `Grid` is in my `DataTemplate` I can not access the `Grid x:Name` anymore in the code behind in .xaml.cs. `books` is a Collection of Books which contains a `Name` and a `Title`

MainPage.xaml

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{x:Bind books}">

<Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Book">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

<Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid 
            x:Name="BooksGrid" 
            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 1 0 0" 
            Margin="0 10 0 0>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

Now I want to acces `BooksGrid` iny the code behind and actually create the `Grid`

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

 private void DrawGrid()
    {

            //create columns of Grid
            for (int i = 0; i < booksize.XProperties.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                BooksGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
                {

                });

            }

            BooksGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = GridLength.Auto;
        }  

     ....
```

Already here at `BooksGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(...)` I get the error that `BooksGrid` can not be found.
My `DrawGrid` works if I do not place the `Grid` definition in my `DataTemplate` and also outside my`Pivot`. So the `MainPage.xaml.cs`does not find it when the `Grid` is inside my `DataTemplate`

I've read that the solution might be that I have to acces the `Grid instance` that I want to work with, as soon as the `DataTemplate` gets loaded. But I do not know how to do that either.

EDIT PART to first solution:

I'm also using `BooksGrid` in another method 
MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void DrawBooksFront(Front front)
    {
        int row;
        int column;
        column = booksize.XProperties.IndexOf(front.CustomProps[booksize.XLabel])+1;
        row = booksize.YProperties.IndexOf(front.CustomProps[booksize.YLabel])+1;
        Frame newFrame = new Frame();
        TaskBoardGrid.Children.Add(newFrame);
        Grid.SetColumn(newFrame, column);
        Grid.SetRow(newFrame, row);


    }
```

Comment: You should not find the DateTemplate and you should use UserControl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you cannot access your `BooksGrid` is because it will be dynamically generated for each book in the `books` collection. So for every book a `Grid` will be generated.

**OPTION 1:**
 You can add a `Loaded` event to your grid:

```
<Pivot x:Name="Pivot" ItemsSource="{x:Bind books}">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Book">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid 
                BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" 
                Margin="0,10,0,0" Loaded="DrawGrid">
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

and in your code behind:

```
    private void DrawGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grid = sender as Grid;
        // Load your grid..
    }
```

**EDIT - OPTION 2:**
If you'd like to access your grids from code behind in a different way (like suggested in your edit) you can always do the following:

```
private void DrawBooksFront(Front front)
{
        // Loop through the pivot's items and get the content from each item's ContentTemplate.
        foreach (var item in Pivot.Items)
        {
            PivotItem pivotItem = Pivot.ContainerFromItem(item) as PivotItem;
            Grid grid = pivotItem.ContentTemplate.LoadContent() as Grid;
            // Do something with the grid.
        }
}
```

Comment: It makes sense to me but I'm also using `BooksGrid` in another method which is called `public void DrawBooksFront(Front front)`. There I am using it like that `BooksGrid.Children.Add(newFrame)`to simply add a `Frame`

Comment: @J.Carden, I edited my answer. I hope that helps you out. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to display previews of the pages of the book inside a `PivotItem` in a grid-like manner [picture below], then you're better off placing `GridView` in a `DataTemplate` of `Pivot.ItemTemplate` and using data binding to display those pages automatically, this would eliminate the need to write the code in `xaml.cs` that you showed.

Please, share more details about your app (what you're given and what the end result should look like) so we could help you better.

[image]